# Оптимизировать оператор IF

Tags: javascript, if

Делаю конвертер валют,и в результате у меня получается идентичный код.
Можно ли его как-нибудь оптимизировать через тернарный оператор?или по другому
Потом еще хочу добавить с USD to UAH или USD to EUR

```js
var exchan=document.getElementById("exchan");
exchan.addEventListener("click",function(e){
 var numberOne=document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
 var numberTwo=document.getElementById("numberTwo");
 var sExchange;
 var currencyOne=document.getElementById("currencyOne").value;
 var currencyTwo=document.getElementById("currencyTwo").value;
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="USD"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursUSD).toFixed(2);
 }
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="EUR"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursEUR).toFixed(2);
 }
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="PLN"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursPLN).toFixed(2);
 }

},false);
```

Comment: Где у вас создаются `cursUSD`, `cursEUR` и `cursPLN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var exchan=document.getElementById("exchan");
exchan.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var numberOne=document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
    var numberTwo=document.getElementById("numberTwo");
    var sExchange;
    var currencyOne=document.getElementById("currencyOne").value;
    var currencyTwo=document.getElementById("currencyTwo").value;
    var typeCurrencyTwo = {
        USD: cursUSD,
        EUR: cursEUR,
        PLN: cursPLN,
    }
    if(currencyOne=="UAH"){
        numberTwo.value=(numberOne/typeCurrencyTwo[currencyTwo]).toFixed(2);
    }
},false);
```